# Is there a style sheet available for OS Open Roads layer?

Tags: qgis, ordnance-survey

I've added this vector layer into QGIS but unlike other layers available from the OS I haven't been able to find a standard style to work with it. Is there anything available out there?

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-roads.html

Comment: Kindly specify your QGIS version...In QGIS 2.8.7(LTR) there are different styles in 'Simple Line' & 'Marker Line' under 'Symbol Layer type' option...You just have to customise the available option to get the best output..

Comment: Not as far as I know, I don't think this dataset is intended for map-making as such, but is more for distances and routing. If you want to use it with mapping I think you'd need to add one of the other OS OpenData vector datasets and style this. Or design your own styles.

Comment: I'm using QGIS version 2.12.2-Lyon, I've tried to use the road style layers that are available for the OS "district" and "local" open layers but they don't work very well. I suppose I could adjust to suit but I'm new to these systems. Just thought that the OS may have created a style to go along with the "road" open layer as well.

Comment: The OS style files for roads in the VM District and the OM Local datasets are confusing. There are three road style files and you have to load the 'roads' shapefile three times and then style each instance using a different style file. It would help if you could add to your question above a brief description of your project.